# What does “slant” mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does *slant* mean here:

> Even if you’re a pro at drawing, you don’t want to skip this 
>   part because you may find some new slants on old skills.

Comment: New aspects, new facets, new elements. There's always something new to discover: one's ability to do something can be expanded. There's always something to learn.

Comment: From Merriam Webster: **[slant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slant)**: a peculiar or personal point of view, attitude, or opinion. (Thus, by reading that part of the text you might discover some fresh ways of looking at old skills, some new approaches)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst (many) others, the OED provides this sense for the noun *slant*:

> 8. A way of regarding something, a point of view or ‘angle’; an interpretation; a bias. *orig. U.S.*

Comment: @user148098 Yes, that’s right. It means new perspectives on old skills.

Comment: @user148098 - yes, as if from "a new angle (slant)"